# Seg2Cat blank values

Tags: snippets, low-seg2cat

I've installed (new) seg2cat on  a new EE upgrade (2.7.2) and it isn't behaving as expected:

`(1.143091 / 6.09MB)      Snippets (Keys): segment_category_ids|segment_1_category_id|segment_1_category_parent_id|segment_1_category_group_id|segment_1_category_name|segment_1_category_description|segment_1_category_image|segment_2_category_id|segment_2_category_parent_id|segment_2_category_group_id|segment_2_category_name|segment_2_category_description|segment_2_category_image|segment_3_category_id|segment_3_category_parent_id|segment_3_category_group_id|segment_3_category_name|segment_3_category_description|segment_3_category_image|segment_4_category_id|segment_4_category_parent_id|segment_4_category_group_id|segment_4_category_name|segment_4_category_description|segment_4_category_image|last_segment_category_id|last_segment_category_parent_id|last_segment_category_group_id|last_segment_category_name|last_segment_category_description|last_segment_category_image|freelancer_version|site_id|site_label|site_short_name|last_segment|current_url|current_path|current_query_string
(1.143106 / 6.09MB)`

Note the blank values here:

`Snippets (Values): 241|||||||||||||||||||241|0|6|Attire for Grooms + Groomsmen||grooms.jpg|241|0|6|Attire for Grooms + Groomsmen||grooms.jpg|FALSE|1|Ashley's Bride Guide|default_site|attire-for-grooms-groomsmen|http://ashleysbrideguide.com/abg.php/nashville-wedding-ideas/gallery/attire-for-grooms-groomsmen/attire-for-grooms-groomsmen|nashville-wedding-ideas/gallery/attire-for-grooms-groomsmen/attire-for-grooms-groomsmen|`

Any ideas why a multitude of snippet values would output blank values without keys? Or numeric values like 241, without keys?

All advice appreciated.

Edit: Posting under low-seg2cat because this bug lead to blank seg2cat values. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For visibility, this is what your snippets look like:

```
[segment_category_ids] => 241
[segment_1_category_id] => 
[segment_1_category_parent_id] => 
[segment_1_category_group_id] => 
[segment_1_category_name] => 
[segment_1_category_description] => 
[segment_1_category_image] => 
[segment_2_category_id] => 
[segment_2_category_parent_id] => 
[segment_2_category_group_id] => 
[segment_2_category_name] => 
[segment_2_category_description] => 
[segment_2_category_image] => 
[segment_3_category_id] => 
[segment_3_category_parent_id] => 
[segment_3_category_group_id] => 
[segment_3_category_name] => 
[segment_3_category_description] => 
[segment_3_category_image] => 
[segment_4_category_id] => 241
[segment_4_category_parent_id] => 0
[segment_4_category_group_id] => 6
[segment_4_category_name] => Attire for Grooms + Groomsmen
[segment_4_category_description] => 
[segment_4_category_image] => grooms.jpg
[last_segment_category_id] => 241
[last_segment_category_parent_id] => 0
[last_segment_category_group_id] => 6
[last_segment_category_name] => Attire for Grooms + Groomsmen
[last_segment_category_description] => 
[last_segment_category_image] => grooms.jpg
[freelancer_version] => FALSE
[site_id] => 1
[site_label] => Ashley's Bride Guide
[site_short_name] => default_site
[last_segment] => attire-for-grooms-groomsmen
[current_url] => http://ashleysbrideguide.com/abg.php/nashville-wedding-ideas/gallery/attire-for-grooms-groomsmen/attire-for-grooms-groomsmen
[current_path] => nashville-wedding-ideas/gallery/attire-for-grooms-groomsmen/attire-for-grooms-groomsmen
[current_query_string] =>
```

The Snippets array also contains the current URI, which is:

```
nashville-wedding-ideas/gallery/attire-for-grooms-groomsmen/attire-for-grooms-groomsmen
```

All of this leads me to conclude you do not have the latest Low Seg2Cat (v2.8.0 at this time) installed. First of all, I don't see the `segment_category_ids_piped` key [that v2.8.0 introduced](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/changelog#v2.8.0). Secondly, there are duplicate segments in the URI (3 and 4 are the same) and only the category vars for segment 4 are set. This was [addressed in v2.7.0](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/changelog#v2.7.0).

The rest of the Seg2Cat vars are empty because they do not match category URL titles, which is intended behaviour, like Derek said. Setting the *Set all segments* option to Yes will do this for all possible segments, hard coded by EE to 9. Since you haven't got these set, and the default was set to Yes from [version 2.6.2](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/changelog#v2.6.2) onward. You've also got the `last_segment_category_...` vars there, so I'm going to guess you've got version 2.6.1 installed.

Comment: Thanks for this. It appears to have been an oversight on my part (this is one of 10 of yesterdays intended downloads and I must have lost track.) I concluded it to be a bug because I was going after segment_3 vars which were not set. I hadn't even noticed at the time that segment_4 was the same - no idea why the client has it configured that way, and I didn't expect it. I ended up moving past it with segment_4 because, well, it's the same.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like expected behaviour to me. I'm assuming that you're seeing this at a URL which has a category slug in `segment_3` and nowhere else, so all of the other Seg2Cat variables are empty.

What was the behaviour you were expecting?

Comment: I posted because the segment_3 vars were blank (because this is a version bug & segment_4's were filled & the same as segment_3's,) and I was trying to use them. Also, I didn't realize it wasn't the latest version or I would have gone straight to download it before posting. Thanks so much for your answer.